Proving the two optimization are equivalent or not
Here are two optimization problems:
$$
(P) : \inf_{x} [ f(x)|g(x) \leq 0 ] \text{ where } g(x) = \inf_{y} [ h(x,y)|y \in Y ] 
$$
$$
(Q) : \inf_{x,y} [f(x)|h(x, y) \leq 0, y \in Y ]
$$
Are they equivalent to each other? Could you provide some counter-example and explain why if they are not? Just give some hint maybe.
I know that Stephen Boyd's Convex Optimization says that "we can always minimize a function by first minimizing over some of the variables, and then minimizing over the remaining ones." But I don't know if it still true in this situation.
I think the most basic idea is to start thinking in terms of some infeasible inf, but I'm a little stuck on that.

They are not equivalent in general: define
$$
h(x,y) = e^x,
$$
then $g(x) =0$ for all $x$, so that (P) is equivalent to
$$
\min f(x).
$$
However, there is no  point $(x,y)$ that is feasible for (Q), i.e.,
$$
\{ (x,y): \ h(x,y) \le0\} = \emptyset.
$$

If in addition, one assumes that the infimum in the definition of $g$ is always attained (for example, $h$ is continuous and $Y$ is compact), then the above problem does not appear, and (P) and (Q) are equivalent

@Albertovsky what exactly do you mean? Because the author of this answer already made it clear that, in the case where there exists a feasible solution, then $(P)$ and $(Q)$ are indeed equivalent
